# How to access secured Spring API with browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

I have a Spring app that I secured with Keycloak. I can access it with a terminal using the following command `curl -X GET http://localhost:9089/my-service/mypage -H 'Authorization: Bearer +access_token'`. Its is a bearer-only type of security.

I followed this tutorial (I had a hard time with french but still I figured it out) https://blog.ineat-conseil.fr/2017/11/securisez-vos-apis-spring-avec-keycloak-2-parametrage-dun-domaine-keycloak/

As a result, I get the HTML code of the corresponding page, which makes me think that it works.

However, when I try to type the link `http://localhost:9089/my-service/mypage`in my browser, it displays a 401 Unauthorized error. I'm using a `@Controller` and not a `@RestController`, even though I'm not sure that makes any significant difference in this case.

It's nice that it works with the terminal, but I can't really use my app with it.

My question is how can I overcome that 401 error so I can actually access my front interface from my browser ?

Comment: silly question (i did not read the article because I do not understand french) but when you just call the URL in your browser, do you supply your authorization header? It looks like you are just typing the URL like google.com, you need to add your bearer token in the header of the request. If youre using chrome I can suggest ModHeader to you, which lets you modify the request headers

Comment: well that's right, but how do you supply the header ? that's actually what I don't know how to do (i'm using Firefox)

Comment: Have you tried in postman ? Or even the same curl command you can pass the headers.

Comment: I did use postman, and I managed to make it work with it as well, but only when I use my browser I get that 401. Is there a way to pass the headers to the browser though ?

Comment: Yes you need to use a suitable plugin that can modify your HTTP requests. Google for a plugin for the browser you use :)

Comment: From my understand that article instructs you on how to secure an *OAuth2 Resource server*. It sounds like you want your application to be an *OAuth2 Client*. If your application is a client, when a user navigates to your HTML page they will be redirected to a login page. Once they log in they will be able to access your page. You can see the client configuration here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client

Comment: My app uses a bearer-only token, and from what I think I understand, a bearer-only app bypasses a login page. Now, does that mean that my user should be "previously" logged in somehow ? That's one thing I can't get my head around